# Using replaceAll with a closure in Groovy

Tags: regex, jenkins, groovy

I have some Groovy code (actually from a Jenkinsfile):

```
           fileNew = fileOld.replaceAll("((D:)((.*)\\\\(.*))*)") {
                    it[0].replaceAll("D:", "/xxx/yyyy")
                    it[0].replaceAll("\\\\", "/")
            }
            writeFile file: 'my-output-file', text: fileNew
```

The code correctly matches the lines marked by the pattern in `fileOld.replaceAll` (as shown if I `println it[0]`) but there is no replacement in the written file. How can I get that to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I'm seeing in the docs [here](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/StringGroovyMethods.html#replaceAll(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence,groovy.lang.Closure)) it wouldn't work to call `replaceAll` inside of the `replaceAll` closure.  I think maybe you just need to do two separate `replaceAll` calls, searching for the `"D:"` and `"\\\\"` separately.

Comment: But I only want to change the "\\\\" in the lines that match the original pattern. Is that possible?

Comment: maybe you could do ````fileNew = fileOld.findAll{"((D:)((.*)\\\\(.*))*)"}.each{it.replaceAll("D:", "/xxx/yyyy") it.replaceAll("\\\\", "/")}````

Comment: Can't use findAll in a Jenkinsfile

Answer (score -1):

I was messing around with some different things and maybe using the original `replaceAll` would work.

```
fileNew = fileOld.replaceAll("((D:)((.*)\\\\(.*))*)") {
     it[0] = it[0].replace("D:", "/xxx/yyyy")
     it[0].replace("\\\\", "/")
}
```

That worked for me but I wasn't positive what `fileOld` would look like so I had to guess a little there.